# Excel 2010 - Date Countdown from existing

Tags: excel

I have varying dates in column H, which happen to be a Rate Expiration Date.  I want to add a countdown in the adjacent column in column G to show how many days I have left until that rate expires. How do I do this?

Comment: Use `H1-TODAY()`, format as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula ,

`=TEXT(H1-TODAY(),"#")`

This prints the number of days between the date in column H and today